# NoSuchElementException when HashMap Iterator hits empty line

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, nosuchelementexception

Hi i'm doing some training on ArrayLists and HashMap.

I'm parsing a file with BufferedReader, add each line to the ArrayList *readList* and now I like to create a HashMap<String,Integer> *map* where the Key is the readList entry and the Value is the line count.

When i use a Lambda command so print the k,v everything works fine. However when i try to use the Iterator to save the k,v to variables, i'm getting a NoSuchElementException error. What am I doing wrong ? (Just fyi when i delete the empty line in the file, everything works fine)

```
        String sourceFile = "newtestfile.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile));
        String line = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> readListe = new ArrayList<>();  

        while(line != null){
            readListe.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<readListe.size() ;i++){
            map.put(readListe.get(i), i+1);
        }

        //map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k));
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> iterator2 = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iterator2.hasNext()){
            String key = iterator2.next().getKey();
            int value = iterator2.next().getValue();

            System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        }



**Source file:** 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren
NewLine ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
This is line 3
//EMPTY LINE
John Doe
//END OF FILE
```

Comment: You are calling `iterator2.next()` twice inside your loop. Not only do you not know if that is possible because your `hasNext()` check only makes sure it has one next element, but also will it give you completely wrong results as you take the key and value from different entries. Call it once in the loop and save the result, then use that result to get key value from that one single call.

Comment: Got it, thanks!I was blended by the fact that it worked with my solution whenever i deleted the empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `while(iterator2.hasNext())` loop you call `iterator2.next()` twice which means that the iterator advances twice each time.

With the empty line present your input has an odd number of lines at that means the last time through the while loop there is no element left for the `iterator2.next().getValue()` call.

It would be better to use the "for-each" idiom:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: map.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        int value = e.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Thomas' answer, here's two more ways to iterate over a `Map`'s entries:

```java
// Iterator and for-loop
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  Map.Entry<String, Integer> e = it.next();
  String key = e.getKey();
  int value = e.getValue();

  System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
// forEach with lambda
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
```